# Line detection techniques available in image processing similar to Hough Transform

Tags: image-processing, line, detection

Is there any line detection techniques available in image processing like Hough Transform??? can u do a comparison between Hough Transform with that techniques

Comment: You can use OpenCV's LSD. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41329665/linesegmentdetector-in-opencv-3-with-python/41679071#41679071

Answer (score 0):

There is. For example Line Segment Detector, aka, LSD. Hough Transform also have different types, like Probabilistic Hough line Transform (PHT). And yes, you can do a comparison between the different types of Hough Transform and Line Segment Detector. Methods are to compare computation speed, false positives and false negatives. Good luck.