# LineSegmentDetector in Opencv 3 with Python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv3.0

Can a sample implementation code or a pointer be provided for implementing LSD with opencv 3.0 and python? HoughLines and HoughLinesP are not giving desired results in python and want to test LSD in python but am not getting anywhere.

I have tried to do the following:

`LSD=cv2.createLineSegmentDetector(0)
 lines_std=LSD.detect(mixChl)
  LSD.drawSegments(mask,lines_std)`

However when I draw lines on the mask I get an error which is:
 LSD.drawSegments(mask,lines_std) TypeError: lines is not a numerical tuple

Can someone please help me with this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately,  the LSD detector had been removed since version 4.1.0: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/3ba49ccecc773592a3e8d68ad9f5b06196dae6b6

Comment: @MaksymGanenko, Are you aware of any similar line segment detectors like LSD?

Comment: @tpk Unfortunately, LSD is hard to beat, but you may try to use `cv2.ximgproc.createFastLineDetector()` from contrib module.

Comment: @MaksymGanenko Yes. It's unfortunate that they had to remove it. Thanks for the tip on `FastLineDetector`.

Comment: Good news! line segment detector is back in opencv 4.5.4

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use cv2.drawSegments function like this:

```
#Read gray image
img = cv2.imread("test.png",0)

#Create default parametrization LSD
lsd = cv2.createLineSegmentDetector(0)

#Detect lines in the image
lines = lsd.detect(img)[0] #Position 0 of the returned tuple are the detected lines

#Draw detected lines in the image
drawn_img = lsd.drawSegments(img,lines)

#Show image
cv2.imshow("LSD",drawn_img )
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

You can check OpenCV [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/db/d73/classcv_1_1LineSegmentDetector.html#a1816a3c27f7c9b8d8acffec14451d4c4).

Comment: By any chance, do you know the contents of `lsd.detect(img)[1]`? Are they the descriptors?

Comment: So if I want to send the width of the detected lines to the function it doesn't returned the lines which its width is equal or greater but it returned all the lines  ? 
               lines = lsd.detect(warped, 10, 10) so do you know how to detect only the lines that their width is greater than specific width ?

Comment: You can apply a filter to delete all the lines lower than 10px

Comment: What does `0` in `cv2.createLineSegmentDetector(0)` mean? Thanks.

Comment: 0 is the line detector mode for no refinement. The enum is defined here: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#gad092a7362b8afb8a905238a41898d98c

Comment: lsd = cv2.createLineSegmentDetector(0) error: OpenCV(4.2.0) ../modules/imgproc/src/lsd.cpp:143: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) Implementation has been removed due original code license issues in function 'LineSegmentDetectorImpl'

Comment: https://answers.opencv.org/question/215800/any-implementation-of-linesegmentdetector-for-python/ ATTENTION: Fast Line Detector which is available in OpenCV 4.x.x.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to draw the lines in OpenCV 3.2.0 with the following:

```
lsd = cv2.createLineSegmentDetector(0)
dlines = lsd.detect(gray_image)
  for dline in dlines[0]:
    x0 = int(round(dline[0][0]))
    y0 = int(round(dline[0][1]))
    x1 = int(round(dline[0][2]))
    y1 = int(round(dline[0][3]))
    cv2.line(mask, (x0, y0), (x1,y1), 255, 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

I am not sure why all of the extra [0] indirection, but that seems to be what it takes to extract the coordinates.

When unpacking OpenCV returns, I have found it helpful to just print the thing on the console. In this case, I did

```
print(dlines)
```

From all of the nested square brackets, I can often work out a solution without having to worry too much about the why and wherefore of it all.

I had previously used a Windows DLL version of LSD that I compiled from the authors' source and called with ctypes.

Comment: This is a good hand made solution, but LSD have a drawSegment function.

Answer (score 3):

old implementation is not available.
Now it is available as follows:

fld = cv2.ximgproc.createFastLineDetector()
lines = fld.detect(image)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works just fine if all you're after is drawing the lines. However, if you want a finer grain control over the lines and their drawing, you can loop over the lines and deal with them individually as suggested. Just a cleaner version would be:

```
mask = np.zeros((img.shape),np.uint8)
lsd = cv2.createLineSegmentDetector(0)
lines = lsd.detect(img)[0]
for l in lines:
    x0, y0, x1, y1 = l.flatten()
    //do whatever and plot using:
    cv2.line(mask, (x0, y0), (x1,y1), 255, 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
```